# razor and cshtml: how to db.Execute for select statement?

Tags: c#, razor

I am doing a quick CSHTML page for the purpose of testing.

I need to access database based on the id parameter on the URL:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
var db = Database.Open("mydatabase_connection");
var query = "select * from myrecord where id =  " + id;
var row = db.QuerySingle(query);
```

//i am able to display the field (called name) of the selected record in the following way:

```
@row.name
```

Obviously, the above approach is subject to security attack. I am hoping to retrieve the record the following way:

```
var query = "select * from myrecord where id=@0";
var row = db.Execute(query, id);
```

However, I get runtime error when retrieving the field value:

```
@row.name
```

What is the correct way of getting the "row" in the second approach?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Database.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.execute%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is for executing a *non-query SQL statement* and returns the count of records affected by the SQL statement as an `Int`.

I think the method you want to use really is [`Database.QuerySingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.querysingle%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), which returns an `Object`.

ie.

```
var query = "select * from myrecord where id=@0";
var row = db.QuerySingle(query, id);
```

Razor:

```
  @row.name
```

---

As far as safety from SQL injection goes, this approach is safe.  You are passing the URL value into your query as a **parameter**.

The **unsafe** way to run the query would be with string concatenation:

```
   var query = "select * from myrecord where id=" + id;
```

Don't do this!  It allows for a malicious user to append SQL statements to your query!  Always use [parameterized queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks!!! The correct command should be db.QuerySingle(query, id). Do you mind updating your post?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question.  You were wondering about the safety of using URL variables with `db.QuerySingle`.  The way you are using the method is safe, since you are passing `id` to the method is as a parameter.  The *unsafe* alternative would be to add the URL variable to the query string directly: `var query = String.Format("select * from myrecord where id={0}", id);` Since you aren't doing that, you're safe :)